# Scroll UISlider Automatically

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uislider

So currently I have a UISlider in a UIViewcontroller that is meant to start animations within subviews when the user slides.. Basically when the user slides I have this battery with a filling in it that fills the empty battery image with a bar to indicate power within a cell, and the user can slide to see the energy the battery has at certain times of the day.

At the moment, when the View loads I would like the UISlider to AUTOMATICALLY start sliding from the beginning of the slider and scroll to the end within, lets say 5 seconds.

I implemented a loop that cycles through all the values of the uislider using this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < [anObject count] - 2; i++)
{
    sleep(.25);
    NSUInteger index = (NSUInteger)(slider.value + 0.5); // Round the number.
    [slider setValue:index animated:YES];
}
```

`[anObject count] - 2` is equal to 62 at this time of day but will change and increment every 15 seconds because I'm fetching data from a server.

But that aside, why doesn't this work? The loop?

**EDIT:**

So heres what I did with NSTIMER

```
[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(animateSlider) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

and `animateSlider` looks like this:

```
- (void)animateSlider:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSLog(@"Animating");
    NSUInteger index = (NSUInteger)(slider.value + 0.5); // Round the number.
    [slider setValue:index animated:YES];
}
```

But no luck... Why isn't NSTimer "firing"..... I remmeber vaguely there was a method that FIRES an nstimer method but not sure if that's needed...

**EDIT:**

Ahh it does need "Fire"....

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(animateSlider) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
[timer fire];
```

But for some reason it only fires once.... Any ideas ?

Comment: Don't use `sleep();` in this case. That will _pause_ the entire application.

Comment: And instead: `setValue:animated:`, or the alike.

Comment: It would be better to use an NSTimer that fires every 0.25 seconds and updates the scroll view . Then when it gets to a certain value you can invalidate the timer. This way you don't have to sleep and you don't have a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"for some reason it only fires once..."

If you changed the NSTimer set up to this:

```
NSTimer *timer = 
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 
                                    target:self 
                                  selector:@selector(animateSlider:) 
                                  userInfo:nil 
                                   repeats:YES];
```

This would schedule the timer on the current run loop immediately.

And since the "repeats" parameter is "YES", you'd then repeat the timer every quarter second, until you invalidate the timer (which you should do when the ending condition is reached, like when the slider reaches its destination).

P.S. You'd need to change the selector method declaration of your timer's target slightly.  [According to Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval%3atarget%3aselector%3auserInfo%3arepeats%3a), "The selector must correspond to a method that returns void and takes a single argument. The timer passes itself as the argument to this method."

So declare "`animateSlider`" like this instead:

```
- (void)animateSlider: (NSTimer *) theTimer;
```

Comment: nothing occurs.... I accidentally was a little overzealous and upvoted this but it isn't "Firing" many times, just once.... let me check out the code ... but my animateSlider method has a log statement and I only notice one log statement... not many... I would assume I'd be getting alot of log statements but im getting only one :/

Comment: You may need to adjust your "`animateSlider`" method slightly. See my edited answer.

Comment: so i adjusted the method but still nothing, just get one log statement "Animating" :/. Anything else you can suggest? Am i supposed to be passing the variable "theTimer" anywhere within the method? i figure I should be but not sure where...

Comment: are you still calling "`fire`" explicitly?  If so, you don't need to.  And no, "`theTimer`" doesn't need to be expliclty passed or referenced.  It's just the timer instance that calls your "`animateSlider`" method.  I'm starting to wonder if your view controller isn't persisting or if the timer is being released or somehow invalidated as quickly as it's being created?

Comment: When you mean explicitly... do you mean outside the method call? Because what I'm doing in the code above is exactly how I have implemented the method and viewcontroller.... Also, the NSTimer variable is placed in viewDidLoad. Not really sure were to go now but I'm close to just saying f*** it.... this is just getting too trivial :/